# WinRAR SFX from commandline keeps creating a parent folder after extraction

Tags: image, console, icons, winrar, sfx

I am trying to program an automatic SFX creator that integrates all the contents (recursively) form a specified folder.

I successfully managed to do it thanks to some answers in different posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28194942/how-can-i-automate-the-building-of-this-winrar-sfx-file) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5183621/how-can-i-create-an-auto-executing-winrar-sfx-file-from-a-batch-file).

The command I used is the following:

`"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRar" a -s -m5 -ep1 -tl -scul -sfx -iicon"C:\InstallerIcon.ico" -iimg"C:\SFXStripe.bmp" -z"c:\winrar_installer_script.txt" "C:\Installer.exe" "C:\Matlab tools"`

And it does "almost" what I want.

The thing is that when I execute the installer,I get on the installation path (`C:\Installation Path`) a folder named `C:\Installation Path\Matlab Tools` with the desired content inside it, instead of having this content directly placed inside `C:\Installation Path`.

---

What I get:

```
<code>+ C:
    + Installation Path
        + Matlab Tools
            + Folder 1
                - File 1.1
                - File 1.2
            + Folder 2
                - File 2.1
                - File 2.2
</code>
```

What I want:

```
<code>+ C:
    + Installation Path
        + Folder 1
            - File 1.1
            - File 1.2
        + Folder 2
            - File 2.1
            - File 2.2</code>
```

---

*My question is:*

**Is there any way to get rid of the original parent folder (Matlab tools), but preserving the structure inside?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simply compress 1 folder in batch with WinRAR command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24397921/simply-compress-1-folder-in-batch-with-winrar-command-line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it... finally!

Just using the flags `-ep1 -r`, along with an asterisk after the original folder `C:\Matlab Tools\*`.

The full instruction remains like this:

```
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRar" a -s -m5 -ep1 -r -tl -scul -sfx -iicon"C:\InstallerIcon.ico" -iimg"C:\SFXStripe.bmp" -z"c:\winrar_installer_script.txt" "C:\Installer.exe" "C:\Matlab tools\*"
```